# Calculus Three time differentiable

Tags: calculus

Hi I need help in this question,

Suppose f:ℝ→ℝ is three times differentiable such that 
f(a)=f'(a)=0 and f(b)=f'(b)=0, (a < b)

Prove that there exist c ∈ (a,b) such that f'''(c)=0

Is applying Rolle's theorem the right way? If it is, how do i go about doing it?

*I'm new to Rolle's theorem but I am not very clear about it either =(*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a good idea. Since $f(a) = 0 = f(b)$, by Rolle's theorem, $f'(c_1) = 0$ for some $c_1 \in (a,b)$. Since $f'(c_1) = 0 = f'(a)$, there exists $c_2 \in (a,c_1)$ such that $f''(c_2) = 0$. Also, $f'(c_1) = 0 = f'(b)$, so there exists $c_3 \in (c_1, b)$ such that $f''(c_3) = 0$. Finally, since $c_2 < c_3$ and $f''(c_2) = 0 = f''(c_3)$, there exists $c$ in between $c_2$ and $c_3$ such that $f'''(c) = 0$. In particular, $c \in (a,b)$.